# Upgrade file not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, upgrade

I have made some changes in my custom module to enable store view field and made a upgrade file to create table to store store id data as follows. but its not working. its not even giving me an error.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('custom/expert_store'))
    ->addColumn('expert_id',Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,null,
        array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
        ),
        'Expert ID'
    )
    ->addColumn('store_id',Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,null,
        array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
        ),
        'Store ID'
    )
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(
            'custom/expert_store',
            array('store_id')
        ),
        array('store_id')
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(
            'custom/expert_store',
            'expert_id',
            'custom/expert',
            'entity_id'
        ),
        'expert_id',
        $installer->getTable('custom/expert'),
        'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(
            'custom/expert_store',
            'store_id',
            'core/store',
            'store_id'
        ),
        'store_id',
        $installer->getTable('core/store'),
        'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
    )
    ->setComment('Expert To Store Linkage Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing the system cache?

Sometimes this helps, if an update Script is not triggered.

If i ran into this issue, i flush all caches and indexes.

If it isn't working after cache/index refresh - do you have the upgrade script named correct with the module versions `upgrade-{old module version}-{new module version}.php` ?

Comment: yes I did it multiple times.

Comment: upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php and in config 1.0.1